# Kinematics - projectile motion on inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Well I've tried everything to solve this problem, spent well over an hour, and have gotten no results.

A particle is thrown over a triangle from one end of a horizontal base it grazes the top vertex of the triangle. It falls on the other end of the base. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are base angles that the sides of the triangle makes with the ground and $\theta$ is the angle of projection, prove that $\tan\theta$ = $\tan\alpha$ + $tan\beta$

After some more work and thinking, I got: $$\tan\alpha + \tan\beta = \frac{\cos(\theta + \alpha)\sin(\theta + \alpha)}{v\sin\theta(\cos(\theta + \alpha) - \sin\theta)}$$

Any way to simplify to get what I want?

Comment: Well, I did show what I got. Showing all my working would be much too hard, and I showed where I got finally from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the horizontal distance from launch point to apex be $a$ and the horizontal distance from apex to landing point be $b$. Let the apex height be $h$.

Get an expression for the range of the projectile in terms of these variables and $\tan \alpha$ and $\tan \beta$.

Equate this to the range of a projectile using standard mechanics.

You will find you have a factor of $V^2/g$ that you need to replace in terms of $h$ and the angles in order to get your solution.

You can find this relationship by working out what the velocity of the projectile is at the apex of the triangle.

I have done this, and it works out (as I originally posted, but have now deleted, because I realised it is too much help for a homework problem).

Comment: how exactly did you come up with this? .....

Comment: which part are you unclear about? I could insert some intermediate lines of algebra if necessary.

Comment: I've removed the solution, because it provided too much help and was not in the spirit of answering "homework" type questions - apologies. But the recipe I give above does work.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to post an answer, as I can't comment.

I've managed to get close

but I will still add my working below in case it can provide any inspiration:

(this may be where I'm wrong...)

$h = \frac{(v\sin{\theta})^2}{2g}$ (from $v^2 = u^2 + 2as$, where $v = 0$)

Where I have said that $h$ is the height of the triangle (which is probably incorrect, but as I've said, just some inspiration)

If we split the triangle down the middle to form two right angled triangles we have the range $x$

$x = \frac{h}{\tan{\alpha}} + \frac{h}{\tan{\beta}}$

the time $t$ for the particle to fall to the ground is given by:

$t = \frac{2v\sin{\theta}}{g}$ (from $v = u + at$ from bottom to top and down again)

distance $d$ traveled in that time = base of triangle = $x$

$d = \frac{2v^2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}}{g}$

$\frac{2v^2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}}{g} = \frac{(v\sin{\theta})^2}{2g\tan{\alpha}} + \frac{(v\sin{\theta})^2}{2g\tan{\beta}}$

perform some cancelling:

$2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta} = \frac{(\sin{\theta})^2}{2\tan{\alpha}} + \frac{(\sin{\theta})^2}{2\tan{\beta}}$

divide through by $\sin{\theta}$ and $\cos{\theta}$

$2 = \frac{\tan{\theta}}{2\tan{\alpha}} + \frac{\tan{\theta}}{2\tan{\beta}}$

divide both sides through by $\tan{\theta}$ and multiply both sides by 2

$\frac{4}{\tan{\theta}} = \frac{1}{\tan{\alpha}} + \frac{1}{\tan{\beta}}$

flip both sides

$\frac{1}{4}\tan{\theta} = \frac{\tan{\alpha}\tan{\beta}}{\tan{\alpha} + \tan{\beta}}$

### **Simplification of OP**

We can use the following formulae into order to simplify your new working:

$\sin{A \pm B} = \sin{A}\cos{B} \pm \cos{A}\sin{B}$

$\cos{A \pm B} = \cos{A}\cos{B} \pm \sin{A}\sin{B}$

This would give us:

$\tan{\alpha} + \tan{\beta} = \frac{(\cos{\theta}\cos{\alpha} + \sin{\theta}\sin{\alpha})(\sin{\theta}\cos{\alpha} + \cos{\theta}\sin{\alpha})}{v\sin{\theta}(\cos{\theta}\cos{\alpha} + \sin{\theta}\sin{\alpha} - \sin{\theta})}$

You can then try and simplify that further :) even if this doesn't work, at least you learnt about the addition formulae!

Comment: The formula you gave for h is that of maximum distance from base. However, I don't think that will be the height :(

Comment: that's where I think I went wrong, it's the only way I could think of for finding the height... it should be close though, as my end result is close to the expected result

Comment: True, hmmm, well I'll continue on the problem and hope you will too :D

Comment: btw wont the 'v' in the distance traveled be v^2 ??

Comment: ahhh, yes it will nice catch! The elimates the v in the final answer, so now there is just a rogue 1/4 :D

Comment: So that's even worse I suppose lol

Comment: Well, after my work I got:

Comment: Uploaded my latest work

Comment: My friend has apparently got a working solution, when his computer stops crashing I can take a look, for the mean time I will have a look at simplifying yours

Comment: do you do A level maths? there are some formulae called the addition formulae that can simplify that, I will update my answer soon

Comment: Sorry I'm afraid not. Thanks, I hope it comes out to what I want :D

Comment: Updated post, at least you can learn about the addition formulae

Comment: Also, I will post my friends solution, from what he says it is simpler than the other solutions so far

Comment: You are correct, that your assumption that $h$ is the max height of the projectile is incorrect! Also the line below "flip both sides" is incorrect algebra...

Comment: ahhh that it is... I will fix that